# Blue Prism - can't spy an element inside of windows application

Tags: windows, blueprism

I need to spy a drop-down list inside of a windows application, but the whole application window got spied (when I click 'highlight' the whole application window is selected). What can I do to select only the drop-down?

Comment: Attempt to spy the elements with the UI Automation or Region spy modes.

Comment: It's working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First understand how the dropdown element is designed
2. Try manually selecting the dropdown element and then check with keyboard keys -to move up/down the list.
3. Then try to replicate the same using global send keys events by passing some click events and then up/down keyboard buttons as the global send keys parameters

This might help